# Laravel Validation rule for multiple categories and each category have multiple subcategories

Tags: php, laravel

I know how to validate multiple categories like:

```
'categories' => 'required|array',
'categories.*' => 'required|exists:categories,id'
```

But I don't know how to validate sub-categories of each category

```
@foreach($attributes as $attribute)
    @if(count($attribute['properties']) > 0)
    <div class="form-group">
        <label  class="col-md-4 control-label">{{ $attribute['title']}} <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select class="form-control {{($attribute['select_many'] == 1) ? 'mt-select2' : ''}}  dynamic attribute_{{$loop->index}}" name="attribute[{{$attribute['id']}}][]"  {{($attribute['select_many'] == 1) ? 'multiple' : ''}}  required style="width: 100%">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                @foreach ($attribute['properties'] as $key => $value)
                    <option value="{{$key}}"  {{( in_array( $key, ( empty($propertiesSelected) ) ? [] : array_unique($propertiesSelected[$attribute['id']]) ) ) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{$value}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand what you need, you can add an extra *`.field_name`*, so your code would be for example:

```
'categories.*.name' => 'required|exists:categories,id'
```

You can also refer to [Validator Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation) if you need more options, it is very well-written.

Comment: I Have Two dimentional array For example category['subcategories'] = [1, 2, 3] and category['id'] = 1

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules), here is an example:

In your `AppServiceProvider` class under `boot` method:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {

        // Extend laravel validation rules
        Validator::extend('subcategories_exist', function ($attribute, $categories, $parameters, $validator) {

            // $categories represent the incoming categories value from client
            foreach ($categories as $subCategories) {

                foreach ($subCategories as $category_id) {

                    // check category existence in database
                    return App\Category::where('id', $category_id)->count() === 1;

                }

            }

        });
    }

    ...

}
```

**Controller:**

```
'categories' => 'required|array|subcategories_exist',
```